# How to apply functions/operators on VueJS custom filter result?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a Vue filter (named `timeconverter`) to change the date format of a string. I want to check if the result of `{{ time | timeconverter }}` is less than the current time.

How can we apply JavaScript functions to the result of the filter?

For example:

```
{{ time | timeconverter }}.length() 

OR:

{{ time | timeconverter }} > Date.now()
```

I want to display a `div` (as seen below) based on whether `{{ time | timeconverter }}` is greater than current time.

```html
<div>
 {{ time | timeconverter }}<span>min</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide more code?

Comment: you can use computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it's possible to invoke the filter directly via `$options.filters.nameOfFilter`:

```html
<div v-if="$options.filters.timeconverter(time) > Date.now()">
  {{ time | timeconverter }}<span>min</span>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.filter('timeconverter', value => moment(value).valueOf())

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    time: '04 Dec 2025 00:12:00 GMT'
  }),
  mounted() {
    console.log('timeconverter', this.$options.filters.timeconverter(this.time))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/moment.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="time" placeholder="time">
  <div v-if="$options.filters.timeconverter(time) > Date.now()">
    {{ time | timeconverter }}<span>min</span>
  </div>
  <div v-else>Nothing to see</div>
</div>
```

Or with computed props to avoid running the filter twice (once in the `v-if` and again inside the `<div>`):

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="filteredTime > Date.now()">
    {{ filteredTime }}<span>min</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    filteredTime() {
      return this.$options.filters.timeconverter(this.time)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
Vue.filter('timeconverter', value => moment(value).valueOf())

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    time: '04 Dec 2025 00:12:00 GMT'
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredTime() {
      return this.$options.filters.timeconverter(this.time)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/moment.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="time" placeholder="time">
  <div v-if="filteredTime > Date.now()">
    {{ filteredTime }}<span>min</span>
  </div>
  <div v-else>Nothing to see</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is "not" possible and not recommendable. Only if you want to use the comparison in you representation of your string you could this, But still I would recommend. If you want to do something like this:

```
{{ time | timeconverter | afterNow}}
```

So first what is a filter:

> The filter’s function always receives the expression’s value (the
> result of the former chain)

So probably you've the parse the result of timeconverter back to a date and the compare it with the current date. And it is "only" usable within a filter

Instead use a method or [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) value.